# Wiremock Success on Second Attempt

Tags: java, wiremock

I have a scenario to test where the request in its first attempt fails and the same request on its second attempt succeeds. How can we mock the same through wiremock? Tried searching but was unable to find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use Stateful Behaviour

http://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/